# Buffer gets get reduced when escaping dot with back slash

Tags: oracle

I have the below query

```
SELECT
     categorymap.id,
     categorytype.name,
     categorytype.value
FROM
     categorymap,
     categorytype
WHERE
     ( categorymap.logfilename = '**hello\.log**' )
     AND ( categorymap.categorytypeid = categorytype.id )
```

Index is available for column logfilename of categorymap table.
I noticed the buffer gets was more when **not** adding "\" before "." in where clause. Both cases, before and after adding "\", index range scan was used on logfilename column as per explain plan.
Could someone please explain what role does '.' play in here in increasing buffer gets?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this:

```
= '**hello\.log**'
```

(maybe it is just `= 'hello\.log'`; double asterisks for **bold**?), then: you didn't escape anything. This query will search the `logfilename` column for exactly such a string: `hello` followed by a backslash `\` followed by a dot `.` followed by `log`.

You'd escape a dot in e.g. regular expression, but there's none here, so ...

Comment: Yes, asterisks for bold, sorry my bad, I noticed the buffer gets got reduced, and thought this is the reason. I just realized my query actually dint return anything, that's why buffer was nothing, Sorry and thanks for your time.